# Не удается добавить содержимое к объекту SplitView

Tags: c#, xaml

```
<SplitView>
   <SplitView.Pane>
   </SplitView.Pane>
   <StackPanel>
   </StackPanel>
</SplitView>
```

При такой структуре ругается на StackPanel, мол

> Не удается добавить содержимое к объекту SplitView

Приложение запускается и работает корректно, только визуальный конструктор не работает, хотя пример взят из книги. Можно это как то исправить?

Нужно это для меню
[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Comment: А что вы вообще хотите этим достичь? У SplitView не бывает содержимого, вот и не удается добавить его.

Comment: SplitView represents a container with two views; one view for the main content and another view that is typically used for navigation commands. Так написано в учебнике.

Comment: И что дальше? Содержимого-то у него все равно нет, только *"two views"*.

Comment: ...main content and another view that is typically used for navigation commands

Comment: Хватит говорить цитатами непонятно откуда. Загляните лучше в [документацию](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.splitview.aspx) - там есть пример.

Answer (score 1):

```
<SplitView>
   <SplitView.Pane>
   </SplitView.Pane>
   <SplitView.Content>
      <StackPanel>
      </StackPanel>
   </SplitView.Content>
</SplitView>
```